# Orbeon - conditional activation of PDF button

Tags: orbeon

I would like to implement in Form Runner process with two actors and following steps:

1. Author fills fields until form instance is valid
2. Author presses Email button
3. Mentor checks received document against compliance
4. Exclusive gate **Does form comply with standards?**
5. Option 1 **Yes** - Mentor switches Boolean field from false() to true() and Author can go to Step 7.
6. Option 2 **No**  - Author goes to Step 1.
7. PDF button is activated, Author is able to press it, print document, sign and send via regular mail

Assumptions: Only one form definition is used, permissions are used to control field visibility
Question: Any idea how to implement Steps 5 and 7. Rest has been done already.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

**Solved** 
I inserted step between 6 and 7: **review** and set appropriate property:

```
  < property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.review.*.*"
  value=' 
  if ("//drukuj = 1")
  then review
  else error-message(message = "Dokument nie jest gotowy do wydruku")
'/>
```

The property checks the value of control **//drukuj**, if it is true then goes to review page otherwise prints error message.